# Is it possible to change PHP HTML output when it was already outputed?

Tags: php

Is it possible to change already outputed contets? I know that craeting output buffer would be OK, but we are talking about already printed content.

That's `index.php`:

```
<html>

Hello

<?php

// Is it possible to change already outputed "Hello" here?

?>
```

I have problem with even making this question clear. Shouldn't it be "Recursive output manipulation with PHP"?

Comment: If the response is already served to the client: no. Unless your response is HTML and you use javascript.

Comment: JavaScript is out of scope of this question considering first picked thing: we are talking backend here, as you suggested client-side manipulation

Comment: Noted, and I understand that. That wasn't the central point of my comment. The central point of my comment is that it is not possible - based on that you appear to preclude output buffering in your original post. Without further specific detail on your scenario I think it's hard to give an answer, so you should consider updating your question. For instance we do not know if your content is already served *or* for instance, if you are generating output rendering to a file instead.

Comment: See @Ed Heal link to docs - it is possible and am doing it right now with `ob_start` and as follows: http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php!

Comment: I see your comment to the @Ed Heal's answer: output buffering is acceptable. So, let me speculate... I imagine you have a script that creates some HTML output. You want to capture this, and do some sort of manipulation afterwards. You haven't clarified what you want to do, but let's assume you want to do some DOM manipulation to this HTML. Yes, this is totally possible, with output buffering and `DOMDocument::loadHTML()`; e.g: `ob_start(); include 'template.php'; /* do stuff here*/ $html = ob_get_clean();` to capture your html as a string and pass to `DOMDocument`.

Comment: `DOMDocument::loadHTML()` part was interesting, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to use these functions http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: Is it exacly answering my question? As I can see docs state: `The Output Control functions do not affect ..., only functions such as echo and data between blocks of PHP code` - that means "Hello" outside of PHP block could not be modified. Your answer is one I was looking for, yet there is a window of possible improvements.

Comment: @Ultra - Why not write sensible code in the first place so you do not write stuff unless you are sure that it is to be sent. Seems a better solution

Comment: Rewriting something ;-) Refactoring not an option

Comment: @ultra - Just laziness not rewriting code that is not working properly. You have to write some code to fix either way. Why not just fix the actual problem rather than its synptoms

Comment: Ed Heal have you ever been editing code for commercial use created years ago that has to be operating after your changes done in reasonable ammount of time? Than you know refactoring is not an option.

Comment: @ultra - Every day. Better to fix the problem rather than its symptoms

Comment: How idealistic you are. Time efficiency is the key. Noone gratz you for good code but for speed.

Comment: @Ultra - Too much haste less speed. It will come back to bite you in the future just fixing the symptoms and not the cause

Answer (score 0):

Here is an assumed implementation, based on your comments:

```
<?php 
// start by capturing output in a buffer to capture the html output
ob_start(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
// next, clean the buffer and assign to variable
$html = ob_get_clean();
// create a DOMDocument and load the captured output
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
// let's do something to the rendered output,
// for example, find the first <p> node and change its value
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
$p = $nodes->item(0);
$p->nodeValue = 'replaced!';

// finally, echo the updated content as normal
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**

Sorry! I didn't see the question was accepted since I wrote this answer. Apologies to @Ed Heal. Incidentally, I agree with Ed's comment - this question suggests that refactoring should be considered because working with buffers can be troublesome, and could be an indicator that a different approach should be considered.

Comment: "working with buffers can be troublesome," - why's that?

Comment: Well, buffering has its uses, but outside of template generation I've rarely seen it in code unless it's been wrapped around large sections of code to fix 'headers already sent' type errors - typically where you have a page with a large amount of `if/else` statements mixing code and output. It's troublesome because it can make debugging more complicated.